# Comparison between xml attributes (xsd)

Tags: xml, xsd

I got this xml code:

```
<s:complexType name="number">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="number" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="start" type:"xs:double"/>
  <xs:attribute name="end" type:"xs:double"/>
<xs:complexType>
```

I want to make sure that the end attribute has a bigger number than start.
How do i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSD 1.1, you can use [Assertions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xs:complexType name="number">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="number" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="start" type="xs:double"/>
        <xs:attribute name="end" type="xs:double"/>
        <xs:assert test="@end gt @start"/>
     </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```